# elastic-serach -- how to execute wildcard kibana query

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to query data from kibana using 
for example if the input format is:

```
message:"someString"
```

and I want to query for all the messages that start with "msg" and contains "789"

(so message:"msgfdfd789fdfd" will fetched).

how I can fetched it with only one condition and not using

```
message: "msg" AND message: "789"
```

I've tried "message:

```
"msg*789*"
```

but it does not works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next query string

message:msg* AND 789